# Constructing Extreme Points in Reflexive Banach Spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A theorem of Lindenstrauss and Phelps states that if $X$ is a separable reflexive Banach space then the unit ball of $X$, $Ba(X)$, has uncountably many extreme points. The proof goes by contradiction and uses the Baire Category Theorem.

Let $X$ be a separable reflexive Banach space (I have a particular one in mind). Suppose we have an uncountable collection of extreme points in $Ba(X^*)$ ($X^*$ is the dual space of $X$).

Is there a "constructive way" to exhibit an uncountable collection of extreme points in $Ba(X)$?

I don't want to appeal to the Lindenstrauss-Phelps result or do anything too fancy.

Comment: Vladimir Fonf worked a lot on such problems. In particular, he proved in 1979 (Funct. Anal.) that each space whose dual has countably many extreme points contains $c_0$. He also proved a necessary and sufficient criterion for nonreflexivity in his Ukrainian Math. J. paper in 1978. You can check in these papers of check with him whether he proved anything you consider constructive (the term which is not completely clear to me in this context). See also his papers with Lindenstrauss and the paper in Bull. London. MS in 1996.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail: I guess by constructive I mean that I would prefer the proof not go by contradiction. Although any reasonably elementary proof would be interesting.